# Transforming between Image coordinate space and screen coordinate space iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to build a document scanning feature. I'm using CIRectangleDetector to detect the edges of my document and then I pass the coordinates received from there to do Perspective Correction. I wanted to allow the user to edit the custom crop boundaries of the document. The issue that I'm running into is that my image is of size ~ (2448x3264) and my screen is of size ~ (375x575). As CIRectangleDetector returns the coordinates in the image space (i.e. relative to size 2448x3264). Does anybody know a way how I can convert the coordinates from image space to screen space and vice-versa?

I have already tried using ratios i.e. from image -> screen i.e if my topLeft corner is (450, 1065), then the corresponding coordinate on my screen would be (450 * 375/2448, 1065 * 575/3264).

Any advice would be much appreciated!!

Comment: It depends on how the image is displayed relative to the screen. Is the image the exact aspect ratio of the screen? No. So either the image is being letterboxed or some of it is off the edges of the screen. You need to take that into account.

Comment: Also I'm not convinced that screen coordinate space is what you want. It almost never is. Presumably the image is being displayed in something, like an image view. Its bounds are what you want to convert from.

Comment: I agree with @matt - the only time I needed to use screen coordinates was the opposite of what you are doing... I needed to convert a subview of my image view (screen coordinates) to the image coordinates. One thing to keep in mind - CoreImage uses the **bottom left** as the "origin" or `CIVector(x:0, y:0)`, not the top left. Flip the Y coordinates and see if that helps.

Comment: @dfd Good point! I always forget about that.